# How to read value of type "IBuffer" as string in c#?

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I copy a variable which is of type IBuffer in C# (UWP app) to a string?  The IBuffer itself doesn't seem to have any methods.  It has Length which seems to be the correct value.  But I cannot see the value in debugger (says requires Native debugging).  Below is the class.  I need to get Data.

```
public sealed class MagneticStripeReaderTrackData : IMagneticStripeReaderTrackData
{
    public IBuffer Data { get; }
```

Comment: `IBuffer` sounds like an interface - you'll need an implementation to see any data.

Comment: Yeah IBuffer interface is from namespace Windows.Storage.Streams

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For example you can use it like this:

```
var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(Data);
var output = dataReader.ReadString(Data.Length);
```

You can find same example here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/hh464978

Comment: Thank you I've needed this for a IoT application

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your IBuffer stream to a DataReader using the FromBuffer method and then using the ReadString method of the DataReader you can retrieve your data as a string.

```
    public string RetrieveStringFromUtf8IBuffer(Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer theBuffer)
    {
        using (var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(theBuffer))
        {
            dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
            return dataReader.ReadString(theBuffer.Length);
        }
    }
```